# Howto increase apache MaxClients in a plesk environment

Tags: apache-2.2

We're currently (not for long but long enough that I need a solution) on a VPS service running plesk and no matter how much we tweak, we can't seem to get the MaxClients above 10. We've set both of these values in a swtune.conf

ServerLimit       50
MaxClients        50

Restart but no effect. We're seeing a message in the logs:

WARNING: Attempt to change ServerLimit ignored during restart

Help. Is this an issue of the way apache was compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first figure out if you are using prefork or worker:

```
 httpd -V
```

then edit your httpd.config

```
nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

I am unfamiliar with swtune.conf, but it looks like probably an include that contains the tuning directives for either prefork/worker...  if it's not taking effect, make sure your httpd.conf is in fact loading it!

- try to stop & start the server ~& not~ a graceful or restart [this is a rumor that server limit needs - I don't know for sure!]
- I sincerely doubt that the plesk apache was compiled with a hard limit of 10, I'm not sure that's even possible.
- ca we see your whole set of directives [cause it sounds like it is trying to load it but failing for some reason]

-sean

Comment: Sean, thanks for this. The hard stop and start seems to have done the trick in taking the swtune.conf settings. I'll comment back if it turns out that I'm mistaken, but this seems to have done the trick.